Show that a group of order $10^6$ surjects onto a group of order at most $10^4.$
The  Problem  is: Let $G$ be a group of order $10^6.$ Show that $G$ admits a nontrivial homomorphism onto a group $H$ of order at most $10^4.$
My  approach Here, $|G|=2^65^6.$ One canonical way to show this is to produce a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ of order at least $10^2.$ So, I was thinking to compute the number of Sylow $2$ ($n_2$) and Sylow $5$-subgroups ($n_5$) in $G$ denoted by $P_2$ and $P_5$ respectively. We have the relations as: $n_2=2k+1\mid 5^6$ and
$n_5=5l+1\mid 2^6.$
So $n_5\in \{1,16\}.$ $n_5=1\implies P_5$ is normal. Then, it contains normal subgroups of order $5,5^2,\cdots,5^5.$ Name the normal subgroup of order $5^2$ by $A.$ But this does not necessarily imply that $A$ is normal in $G.$
Also, $n_2\in \{1,5,5^2,5^3,5^4,5^5\}.$ Similarly as above, there exist a normal subgroup of order $2^2$ in a Sylow $2$-subgroup. But, I can't proceed after that. Again, $n_5=16$ implies there are $16$ subgroups of order $5^6.$ As, $|G|\nmid n_5!=16!$ hence we still have a nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ in $G,$ then we can take internal direct product of $N$ with a subgroup of order $2^2$ but then I am yet to know the order of $N.$
Also, I was looking at the centre of $G.$ Can we somehow infer that $Z(G)$ has order at least $10^2 ?$ Thanks in advance for any hints.

If $P_5$ is normal, you’re done, because $\vert P_5 \vert = 5^6 \gt 10^2$.

And if $n_5=16$ then, since a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $S_{16}$ has order $5^3$, the kernel of the conjugation action of $G$ on its Sylow $5$-subgroups has order at least $5^3 > 10^2$.

Note also that Burnside's $p^\alpha q^\beta$ theorem shows that all such groups are solvable, so there is a nontrivial homomorphism onto a group of order $2$ or $5$, but presumably you are not supposed to use that result!

Use **text** for text.
